# Making a Python script to ping websites

Tags: python

So I know not all of this is correct but this is what I have. I'm just trying to write a script that can ping google or yahoo by selecting 1 or 2 and a third option to enter a custom URL if anyone could help me out with that Id appreciate it.

```
import os
print('1. Ping Google')
print('2. Ping Yahoo')
print('3. Ping custom URL')

key = input('Input your choice: ')
if key == 1:
    os.system("ping google.com")
elif key == 2:
    os.system("ping yahoo.com")  
elif key == 3:
input('Enter URL: ')
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? you seem to already know how to read user input.

Comment: code seems work just fine. what part do you need help with? for option 3., complete it with `url = raw_input('Enter URL: ');
    os.system("ping " + url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got this fixed up a bit and mostly works:

```
from os import system
print('1. Ping Google')
print('2. Ping Yahoo')
print('3. Ping custom URL')
key = int(input('Input your choice: '))
if key == 1:
        system("ping www.google.com")
elif key == 2:
        system("ping www.yahoo.com")
elif key == 3:
        url = input('Enter URL: ')
        system("ping " + url)
else:
        print("Invalid Option!")
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't expecting a reply so quickly

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example code which provide message according to ping status for any web address (like: google.com) . If response "ok" then show "ALIVE" otherwise will show exception message.

Example platform for Raspberry-pi using python:

```
import requests
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get('http://google.com')
        print(int(response.status_code))
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
                print "ALIVE"
        else:
                GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
                print "DISCONNECTED"
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print "NO INTERNET"
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        print str(e)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
print('1. Ping Google')
print('2. Ping Yahoo')
print('3. Ping custom URL')

key = input('Input your choice: ')
if key == 1:
    os.system("ping google.com")
elif key == 2:
    os.system("ping yahoo.com")
elif key == 3:
    url=raw_input('Enter URL: ')
    os.system("ping %s" %url)
else:
    print("invalid input")
```